python can not read json file with encoding = 'utf8'
I can not read full text with this json file:
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "test",
      "timestamp_ms": 1554347140802,
      "content": "Ch\u00c3\u00a0o Anh/Ch\u00e1\u00bb\u008b, Anh/Ch\u00e1\u00bb\u008b vui l\u00c3\u00b2ng \u00c4\u0091\u00e1\u00bb\u0083 l\u00e1\u00ba\u00a1i S\u00e1\u00bb\u0090 \u00c4\u0090I\u00e1\u00bb\u0086N THO\u00e1\u00ba\u00a0I + T\u00c3\u008cNH TR\u00e1\u00ba\u00a0NG B\u00e1\u00bb\u0086NH \u00c4\u0091\u00e1\u00bb\u0083 D\u00c6\u00af\u00e1\u00bb\u00a2C S\u00c4\u00a8 CHUY\u00c3\u008aN M\u00c3\u0094N s\u00e1\u00ba\u00afp x\u00e1\u00ba\u00bfp t\u00c6\u00b0 v\u00e1\u00ba\u00a5n v\u00e1\u00bb\u0081 s\u00e1\u00ba\u00a3n ph\u00e1\u00ba\u00a9m, b\u00e1\u00bb\u0087nh t\u00c3\u00acnh c\u00e1\u00bb\u00a5 th\u00e1\u00bb\u0083 v\u00c3\u00a0 li\u00e1\u00bb\u0087u tr\u00c3\u00acnh ph\u00c3\u00b9 h\u00e1\u00bb\u00a3p cho Anh/Ch\u00e1\u00bb\u008b nh\u00c3\u00a9.",
      "is_geoblocked_for_viewer": false
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "",
      "timestamp_ms": 1554334611125,
      "content": "T\u00c3\u00b4i mu\u00e1\u00bb\u0091n \u00c4\u0091\u00e1\u00ba\u00b7t h\u00c3\u00a0ng",
      "is_geoblocked_for_viewer": false
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "test",
      "timestamp_ms": 1554334610788,
      "content": "Ch\u00c3\u00a0o Musickhc! Ch\u00c3\u00bang t\u00c3\u00b4i c\u00c3\u00b3 th\u00e1\u00bb\u0083 gi\u00c3\u00bap g\u00c3\u00ac cho b\u00e1\u00ba\u00a1n?",
      "is_geoblocked_for_viewer": false
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "test",
      "timestamp_ms": 1554334609955,
      "content": "Customer \u00c4\u0091\u00c3\u00a3 tr\u00e1\u00ba\u00a3 l\u00e1\u00bb\u009di tin nh\u00e1\u00ba\u00afn ch\u00c3\u00a0o m\u00e1\u00bb\u00abng t\u00e1\u00bb\u00b1 \u00c4\u0091\u00e1\u00bb\u0099ng c\u00e1\u00bb\u00a7a b\u00e1\u00ba\u00a1n. \u00c4\u0090\u00e1\u00bb\u0083 thay \u00c4\u0091\u00e1\u00bb\u0095i ho\u00e1\u00ba\u00b7c g\u00e1\u00bb\u00a1 l\u00e1\u00bb\u009di ch\u00c3\u00a0o n\u00c3\u00a0y, h\u00c3\u00a3y truy c\u00e1\u00ba\u00adp ph\u00e1\u00ba\u00a7n C\u00c3\u00a0i \u00c4\u0091\u00e1\u00ba\u00b7t tin nh\u00e1\u00ba\u00afn.",
      "is_geoblocked_for_viewer": false
    }
  ]
}

I am using this code:
with open('message_1.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
    print('message', data)
    file.close()

The result is
{'messages': [{'sender_name': 'test', 'timestamp_ms': 1554347140802, 'content': 'ChÃ\xa0o Anh/Chá»\x8b, Anh/Chá»\x8b vui lÃ²ng Ä\x91á»\x83 láº¡i Sá»\x90 Ä\x90Iá»\x86N THOáº\xa0I + TÃ\x8cNH TRáº\xa0NG Bá»\x86NH Ä\x91á»\x83 DÆ¯á»¢C SÄ¨ CHUYÃ\x8aN MÃ\x94N sáº¯p xáº¿p tÆ° váº¥n vá»\x81 sáº£n pháº©m, bá»\x87nh tÃ¬nh cá»¥ thá»\x83 vÃ\xa0 liá»\x87u trÃ¬nh phÃ¹ há»£p cho Anh/Chá»\x8b nhÃ©.', 'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False}, {'sender_name': '', 'timestamp_ms': 1554334611125, 'content': 'TÃ´i muá»\x91n Ä\x91áº·t hÃ\xa0ng', 'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False}, {'sender_name': 'test', 'timestamp_ms': 1554334610788, 'content': 'ChÃ\xa0o Musickhc! ChÃºng tÃ´i cÃ³ thá»\x83 giÃºp gÃ¬ cho báº¡n?', 'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False}, {'sender_name': 'test', 'timestamp_ms': 1554334609955, 'content': 'Customer Ä\x91Ã£ tráº£ lá»\x9di tin nháº¯n chÃ\xa0o má»«ng tá»± Ä\x91á»\x99ng cá»§a báº¡n. Ä\x90á»\x83 thay Ä\x91á»\x95i hoáº·c gá»¡ lá»\x9di chÃ\xa0o nÃ\xa0y, hÃ£y truy cáº\xadp pháº§n CÃ\xa0i Ä\x91áº·t tin nháº¯n.', 'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False}]}
Can someone help me how to read this file with utf-8 ?
Thanks

use json.load()

You did read the file. I do not understand. You even present an ouput from succesfully reading the file. The file doesn't sem to contain any special characters, does it? why specify encoding at all?

hi @KamilCuk, for example, I want ChÃ\xa0o to Chào

That's exactly what your file contains. Whatever produced this file messed up, not your code.

Actually, if i put the content if the strings  in https://dencode.com/string/unicode-escape i get the same ouput as you presented. Your file is what it is.

Please provide a [mcve], along with both the output you expect and the one you got instead. Give reasons why you think the output is incorrect and should be different. As it stands, it's not clear what you perceive as problem here.

Unfortunately, whatever generated this JSON file has mangled it by encoding Unicode characters as UTF-8, then encoding them as separate code points in the file.
For example, à should be written as \u00e0 directly, but instead it is written as \u00c3\u00a0.
Your JSON file is broken. You have two options:

tell whoever or whatever generated your JSON file to output correctly formed JSON. JSON uses UTF-16 escapes for encoding Unicode characters.
If you cannot control your JSON file, you’ll need to fix it. One option is to walk over the file and fix every broken field. For example:

for message in data["messages"]:
    message["content"] = message["content"].encode("latin1").decode("utf8")


You don't need to parse the file (and walk over the fields) to fix the encoding, do you? Just read, recode and json.loads.

The file contains \u00c3 escapes in the string literals themselves. Reading those with a JSON parser is the most reliable way to resolve those escapes.

I just done it:
from operator import itemgetter


with open('message_1.json', 'r', encoding='raw_unicode_escape') as file:
    messages = json.loads(file.read().encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode())
    print(messages)
    file.close()

But dont know if there are some way better

you don't need to close the file when opening it with context manager (with...) that's the point
